# Syntax error in SQlite Query,(Can't execute)

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

```
class Assets:
    def __init__(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('FastFood.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        self.Cash = input('Do you want to enter Cash:')
        self.Equipment = input('Do you want to enter Eqiupment:')
        self.Supplies = input('Do you want to enter Supplies:')
        self.PrepaidInsurance = input('Do you want to enter Prepaid Insurance:')
        self.ARecievale = input('Do you want to enter Accounts Recievable :')
        query = c.execute('INSERT INTO  Financial_Table (Account_Title)VALUES', (self.Cash))
        result = conn.execute(query)
        conn.close()
```

''' I am tring to insert entry into one column but it's giving a syntax error.'''
'''We have total 4 columns'''

Comment: just look at this:

Comment: query = c.execute('INSERT INTO Financial_Table (Account_Title)VALUES', (self.Cash)) result = conn.execute(query) conn.close() ''' I am tring to insert entry into one column but it's giving a syntax error.''' '''We have total 4 columns'''

Comment: What is the exact syntax error?

Comment: this is exactly the error "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "VALUES": syntax error"

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58990785/edit) your question to format the code, add the error and show us what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: In pure SQL, your `INSERT` statement should look like `INSERT INTO Financial_Table (Account_Title)VALUES('some_value')`.  In your application, you should find a way to pass in the values in a parameterized form.  Something like: `'INSERT INTO Financial_Table (Account_Title)VALUES(%s)', ('some_value');`

Comment: If we are executing it by connection cursor then query should be in string?

Comment: @ravioli it got solved. Thankyousomuch :)

Comment: Awesome :)  No problem.